# Qt5 - Get Content Length while downloading a file from an Url

Tags: qt, download, httprequest, qt5

I am downloading an ".apk" file from a Url with Get method.
The file successfully donwload on my disk from the server.
I actually want to add a progressbar to my program. THE problem is : I can show the bytesReceived but I can't show the totalBytes of the file I am downloading (ContentLenth). How can I get it please from the server.

Here is what i get on my qDebug while downloading:

```
    3498 of -1
    799062 of -1
    1923737 of -1
    3037550 of -1
    3200231 of 3200231
```

Here is my code:

```
void DownloadApk::LaunchDownload()
{
    QNetworkProxy proxy;
    proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy);
    proxy.setHostName("proxy");
    proxy.setPort(8080);
    QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);


    QUrl url("I put my Url here");
    QNetworkRequest request(url);


  _file = new QFile("C:/Users/Desktop/testdownload/downloadedFile.apk");
  _file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);


  QNetworkAccessManager *_manager= new QNetworkAccessManager;
  _reply = _manager->get(request);// Manager is my QNetworkAccessManager
  _file->write(_reply->readAll());
  connect(_reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
            this, SLOT(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
  connect(_reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)),
            this, SLOT(updateProgress(qint64, qint64)));
  connect(_reply, SIGNAL(finished()),
            this, SLOT(finished()));
}


void DownloadApk::error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError err)
{qDebug() << err;
    // Manage error here.
    _reply->deleteLater();
}
void DownloadApk::updateProgress(qint64 read, qint64 total)
{   
    qDebug() << read <<"of"<<total ;
    QByteArray b = _reply->readAll();
    QDataStream out(_file);
    out << b;
}

void DownloadApk::finished()
{
     QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Complete"), tr("Successfully Downloaded"));
    // Done
    _reply->deleteLater();
    _file->close();
    // probably delete the file object too
}
```

Comment: Does the server provide content length to you? Do you have a wireshark trace to back it up?

Comment: You were right! I taught that the contentLength was sent automatically on http header. I was wrong obviously. I corrected my API. This Qt code works correctly. Thank you for your time @Kuba Ober

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. Actually it was not a QT problem. This Qt code works correctly.
The probleme was from the server that wasn't sending ContentLenth on the header of the reply.